# ccs compiler multiple compilation units feature

Tags: compiler-construction, embedded, toolchain

When using the CCS compiler's multiple compilation units feature, I stumbled upon what seems to be a pretty serious bug:

The setup is a header file defining a #bit in a #byte, two compilation units #include-ing the header file and a function referring to said #bit.

It seems that the function's code (specifically using the correct address to said #bit) depends on said function resides in the same compilation unit as the main() function.

Any ideas?

Comment: you might want to post a bit of an example - I'm not sure what the problem you're asking about is.

Comment: I will, as soon as I get hold of that environment again (will take a while, long story...). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a compiler, CCS has a large incidence of bugs (I've worked with it for years).  They also release updated versions about once a month.  It may easily be a bug, multiple compilation units is a relatively new feature in the CCS compiler.

It might help to mirror your question on [CCS' peer support forum](http://www.ccsinfo.com/forum/) and to e-mail their support.